# Jenkins : which plugin needs to be installed to get the build trigger option "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling"

Tags: github, jenkins

When trying to automatically trigger Jenkins jobs using Github WebHook, the build trigger option has to be set to GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling but i dont find this option. which plugin needs to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the configuration option you want you need to install the [GitHub Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/).
It will then add the **GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling** under the **Build Triggers** configuration section.

[image]

In the plugin manager it will appear as:
[image]